# Template deduction from pointer-to-members, where at least one pointer-to-member is known

Tags: c++

Consider a struct with static method templates that accept pointer-to-member functions. Note that when one of the arguments to the methods is an actual pointer-to-member function, both template parameters can be deduced, regardless if the other argument is a `nullptr` or not.

See questions below the following code:

```
struct Checker
{
    template <typename T, typename V>
    static void Check(
        V(T::*getter)(),
        void(T::*setter)(V)
    );

    template <typename T, typename V>
    static void CheckDefault(
        V(T::*getter)() = nullptr,
        void(T::*setter)(V) = nullptr
    );
};

struct Test
{
    int Value();
    void Value(int);

    int Getter();
    void Setter(int);
};

Checker::CheckDefault(&Test::Value);           //1
Checker::CheckDefault(&Test::Value, nullptr);  //2
Checker::Check(&Test::Value, nullptr);         //3

Checker::CheckDefault(&Test::Getter);          //4
Checker::CheckDefault(&Test::Getter, nullptr); //5
Checker::Check(&Test::Getter, nullptr);        //6
```

- Why can the correct overload of `&Test::Value` be determined in 1, but not in 2 and 3?
- Why are 1 and 4 able to deduce the correct typenames, but 2, 3, 5 and 6 not?

---

### Edit

I was expecting to be able to call the methods with at least one of the two arguments set to an actual pointer-to-member function, causing deduction to succeed. Like so:

```
Checker::Check(&Test::Value, &Test::Value); // Both getter and setter
Checker::Check(&Test::Value, nullptr); // Only getter
Checker::Check(nullptr, &Test::Value); // Only setter
```

---

### Edit

The discussion in the excepted answer by @Oliv explaining why it doesn't work as I expected, pointed me in the right direction for solving my specific problem.

I ended up using forwarders, as @Ben Voigt suggested. Something like:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
using GetterT = V(T::*)();

template <typename T, typename V>
using SetterT = void(T::*)(V);

template <typename T, typename V>
void Checker::CheckGetterAndSetter(
    GetterT<T, V> getter,
    SetterT<T, V> setter
)
{
    // Do stuff with getter and setter.
}

template <typename T, typename V>
void Checker::CheckGetter(
    GetterT<T, V> getter
)
{
    SetterT<T, V> null = nullptr;
    return CheckGetterAndSetter(getter, null);
}

template <typename T, typename V>
void Checker::CheckSetter(
    SetterT<T, V> setter
)
{
    GetterT<T, V> null = nullptr;
    return CheckGetterAndSetter(null, setter);
}
```

Comment: Your question is more "why template argument deduction succeed when using the default argument and fails when not?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR It succeeds because *default arguments are not used for template argument deduction*. In the others cases (2,3,5,6) it fails because `nullptr_t` has not the form of a `T(U::*)(V)` (not even a `T*`).

Let's take a simpler example:

```
template<class T>
void f(T,T*=nullptr);
int main(){
  f(10,nullptr);// (1) error
  f(10);// (2) OK
  }
```

For (1) the compiler considers it should be able to deduce `T` from both the first argument and second arguments because a parameter of the form `T` or `T*` are *deductibles*. Since `nullptr_t` as not the shape of a `T*` the compilation fails.

For (2) the compiler only performs template argument deduction for the first parameter of the function because *default arguments does not play in template argument deduction*. So it deduces without ambiguity that `T` is `int`. Then when the function will be called, `nullptr` will be *converted* to a `int*`.

Comment: I now understand I was wrong in thinking that calling `Checker::CheckDefault(&Test::Value)` is a sort of "shorthand" and the compiler calls it as `Checker::CheckDefault(&Test::Value, nullptr)`, substituting the missing argument with its default value.

Comment: Although this raises the question what a valid "empty" argument would be to a pointer-to-member  function?

Comment: @jvdh: If the first argument is always specified, and the second maybe not, you can simply remove the second from consideration during deduction.  e.g. `template <typename T, typename V>
    static void Check(
        V(T::*getter)(),
        identity_t<void(T::*)(V)>::type setter
    );`

Comment: @jvdh What is proposed in this previous comment is to make the second argument always a *non deductible context*, that is a solution if you always provide a first "deductible from" argument.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I left out the other examples (setting the first argument to `nullptr` and the second to a valid pointer-to-member function) for brevity. See updated question.

Comment: @Oliv A I see what you mean. However, the signatures for getters and setters are different in this case, so I'm having trouble catching both in one template.

Comment: @jvdh: Then use that one for when the first argument is specified, plus a forwarder for when it isn't `template <typename T, typename V>
    static void Check( nullptr_t, void(T::*setter)(V) ) { V(T::*null_getter)() = nullptr; Check(null_getter, setter); }`