# Passing a function pointer to a template in C++

Tags: c++

I have come across this code snippet in C++:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename V>     
static void Check(V(T::*getter)(), identity_t<void(T::*)(V)>::type setter);
```

You can see it in the comment section of this post:

[Template deduction from pointer-to-members, where at least one pointer-to-member is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073904/)

I have also seen similar snippets which look like this:

```cpp
identity_t<void(some::input)>
```

I can't understand this syntax. Is `identity_t` taking in a function pointer of type `void`? What would the definition of `identity_t` look like?

Comment: `identity_t` should be similar to [std::type_identity_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity). That disallows deduction because of the `::type`.

Comment: My question is the actual syntax. What does `void(some::input)` mean here, it it a function pointer of type void?

Comment: it is a signature: function taking `some::input`, and returning `void`, as you might find for `std::function<void(int)>`.

Comment: is this syntax only used within templates?

Comment: Not necessary template: for pointer on function, you might use `void (*)(int);` you might also use intermediate typedef: `using callback_t = void(int); callback_t* c = my_func;`.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67159497/4117728